# Data resample problem (R Studio)==> Bootstrap on the GARCH Coefficient

Tags: r, bootstrap, garch

I would like to resample several data in a vector in order to apply a bootstrap method on my GARCH coefficient.

I have just read the `boot` package and `resample` package nonetheless, they are explaining the code in order to do a bootstrap with a "statistic" (that if I understand well, could be the mean, the median).

In my case I just want to resample the data several times. Is there any other possibilities in these packages (`boot` & `resample`) or should I download another package to do so?

Comment: I am not sure of the details of your bootstrap, Generally, for a nonparametric bootstrap based on $n$ observations,
one takes repeated resamples of size $n$ without
replacement. If `x` is the sample of size $n,$ then
the R code `x.re = sample(x, n, repl=T)` provides one
resample. You can use 'replicate' or some other loop
structure to get a large number of such resamples.

Comment: @BruceET thanks for the answer! Concerning my research, I want to see if the volatility of the GBP/EUR has changed before and after the EU Referendum. Therefore, let's say that T1 is the time series before the Brexit and that T2 is the time series after the Brexit. I will resample the observation 500 times in order to generate 500 new GARCH coefficients in both time series. Then I will subtract these resampled coefficient in order to create a distribution of their difference and finally I will see if the observed coefficient difference (from histor data) is rejected or not.